# Deploying Docker Image with Jenkins on Heroku Container Registry

Tags: docker, heroku, jenkins

I'm trying to deploy [jenkinsci/docker](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker) on Heroku, and have a problem with composing my [Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/romasks/2fcec64eda3b5db32fb793bb1b5f57b8).

When I'm pushing the Docker Image on Heroku Container Registry by `heroku container:push web`, I'm getting an error `Your Docker image must specify a 'CMD' instruction`.

But what command I have to write to run Jenkins inside the container on Heroku?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since heroku containers are ephemeral, where are you savings your jenkins config project settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is referring to the missing [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) stanza in your `Dockerfile`.

But you don't need to create your own docker image and `Dockerfile` if you are not planning to modify anything from the upstream version of the [`jenkins`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker) image (as reflected by the link you provided to the `Dockerfile`).

You can just `docker pull jenkins/jenkins:lts` locally then tag it using `docker tag jenkins/jenkins:lts registry.heroku.com/<app>/<process-type>` and then push it to Heroku using the new tag `docker push registry.heroku.com/<app>/<process-type>`

You can read more on [Heroku's official documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#pushing-an-existing-image) about this topic.

EDIT:

If you do need a custom jenkins docker image for example to install additional jenkins plugins (like the OP needs) you will end up creating your own `Dockerfile` and you will have to do something like this:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh gitlab-plugin publish-over-dropbox
CMD ["--debug=5"]
```

Although we don't need it in a normal environment, we are adding a `CMD` stanza just to pass the `heroku container:push` check that requires a `CMD` stanza in the `Dockerfile`, the `--debug=5` is detected by the `jenkins.sh` `ENTRYPOINT` script and sent to the `jenkins.war` program, in turn this sets the debug level to 5 (the default level if not specified) which in turn does not affect us in any way.

EDIT #2:

Because heroku does not accept more than one instruction for `ENTRYPOINT` you must deviate further from a normal `Dockerfile` scenario and cancel the `ENTRYPOINT` upstream stanza by setting it to `[]` because it is not compatible with heroku and then place everything in the `CMD` stanza:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh gitlab-plugin publish-over-dropbox
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Xms256m -Xmx512m
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD /bin/tini -s -- /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh --httpPort=$PORT
```

I added `JAVA_OPTS` to coupe with a free tier dyno since jenkins and java are memory hungry applications, adjust as needed.

I added the `-s` flag to `tini` because it does no longer have `PID 1`, more on that [here](https://github.com/krallin/tini#subreaping).

I added `--httpPort=$PORT` flag sent to `jenkins.war` so that heroku can populate the proper `$PORT` for the app.

Note from heroku docs:

> ENTRYPOINT is optional. If not set, /bin/sh -c will be used

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: But if I want to install some plugins on Jenkins as you can see at the commented line in my `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Thanks, @Nikolae. It's very helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

Now I have another problem when I'm trying to deploy jenkinsci/docker on Heroku:

> 2017-10-27T15:53:37.569477+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>
> 2017-10-27T15:53:35.856897+00:00 app[api]: Deployed web (dce6a8335a9a) by user roman.skaskevich@gmail.com
>
> 2017-10-27T15:53:35.856897+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user roman.skaskevich@gmail.com
>
> 2017-10-27T15:53:53.949433+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command '--debug\=5'
>
> 2017-10-27T15:53:56.142034+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: No such file or directory
>
> 2017-10-27T15:53:56.243216+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>
> 2017-10-27T15:53:56.228817+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 126

Comment: Edit your question, this isn't an answer!